# colors keep randomizing on sectionList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, native

Hi I have a sectionList that is passed an array of colors + background imgs that are chosen at random to render as a background of each row item. When I swipe to access that view the colors flicker for a few seconds as the random selection is still occurring. Each time I return to the screen with the list, the colors will flicker for a few seconds then settle. how can I have no flickering and the random selection of color happen once at load?

```
            class Main extends React.Component {
                constructor(props, context) {
                super(props, context);

                // app state
                this.state = {
                    listColor: [
                    ['rgba(0,36,155,0.8)', 'rgba(26,0,87,0.8)'],
                    ['rgba(155,0,0,0.8)', 'rgba(87,0,0,0.8)']],
                }
                }


            _handleRandomIndex(arr) {
                return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
            }

            _renderItem = ({item, section}) => (
                <TouchableScale
                        style={styles.row}
                        onPress={this._onRowPress.bind(this, item)}
                        activeScale={0.94}
                        tension={0}
                        friction={3}
                        >
                        <View style={ styles.elevationLow } borderRadius={9} > 
                            <ImageBackground source={{uri: this._handleRandomIndex(item.bgImgs).image_link }} borderRadius={9} style={ styles.imageBackground }>
                                <LinearGradient
                                        colors={ this._handleRandomIndex(this.state.listColor) }
                                        start={[0.1,0.1]}
                                        end={[0.5,0.5]}
                                        style={{ padding: 20, borderRadius: 9 }}>

                                </LinearGradient>
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </View>  
                        }
                </TouchableScale>
            )
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing a Math.random every re-render. So whenever the render function calls, it is changing the color.

Change to this:

```
function _handleRandomIndex(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}

class Main extends React.Component {
    state = {
        listColor: [
            ['rgba(0,36,155,0.8)', 'rgba(26,0,87,0.8)'],
            ['rgba(155,0,0,0.8)', 'rgba(87,0,0,0.8)']
        ]
    }

    _renderItem = ({ item, section }) => <Item item={item} listColor={this.state.listColor} />
}

class Item extends Component {
    rando = _handleRandomIndex(this.props.listColor);

    render() {
        const { item } = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableScale
                style={styles.row}
                onPress={this._onRowPress.bind(this, item)}
                activeScale={0.94}
                tension={0}
                friction={3}
            >
                <View style={styles.elevationLow} borderRadius={9}>
                    <ImageBackground source={{ uri: this._handleRandomIndex(item.bgImgs).image_link }} borderRadius={9} style={styles.imageBackground}>
                        <LinearGradient
                            colors={this.rando}
                            start={[0.1, 0.1]}
                            end={[0.5, 0.5]}
                            style={{ padding: 20, borderRadius: 9 }}>

                        </LinearGradient>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </View>
            </TouchableScale>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although all row items render the same color, do you know how to render them different colors?

Comment: @MatthewSimms do you want even rows to be a specifc color, and odd rows a specific color? Or every single one a random color? Show me the `render` function in of `Main` component. The way to do this is break out `renderItem` into a component of its own, and in its constructor generate the color.

Comment: every single row to be a random color

Comment: @MatthewSimms see updated post. You had to break the item into its own component with its own constructor. In the constructor of it, i set rando.

Answer (score 0):

Noitidart's answer will work but all the items will be randomized to same color, if you want each item a different color I think you need to do this:

```
_renderItem = ({item, section}) => {
          const color = this._handleRandomIndex(this.state.listColor);
          return (
            <TouchableScale
                    style={styles.row}
                    onPress={this._onRowPress.bind(this, item)}
                    activeScale={0.94}
                    tension={0}
                    friction={3}
                    >
                    <View style={ styles.elevationLow } borderRadius={9} > 
                        <ImageBackground source={{uri: this._handleRandomIndex(item.bgImgs).image_link }} borderRadius={9} style={ styles.imageBackground }>
                            <LinearGradient
                                    colors={ color }
                                    start={[0.1,0.1]}
                                    end={[0.5,0.5]}
                                    style={{ padding: 20, borderRadius: 9 }}>

                            </LinearGradient>
                        </ImageBackground>
                    </View>  
                    }
            </TouchableScale>
          )
        }
```

Comment: Yes Noitidart solution all colors are the same. Your solution the colors are still flickering on re render, any other ideas?